# make a circle from dots using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

Could some help me to draw a circle using matplotlib or matplotlib and numpy. I have a set of points with x and y coordinates. [set of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoJt7.png)

Then I need to take from this set dots that will make a circle. The result should be something [a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdRNV.jpg)

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = list(range(1, 101))
Y = list(range(1, 101))


x = numpy.array(X)
y = numpy.array(Y)

xgrid, ygrid = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(xgrid, ygrid, s=5, color='green')

ax.set_title('net 100х100',
    fontfamily = 'monospace',
    fontstyle = 'normal',
    fontweight = 'bold',
    fontsize = 10)
ax.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax.axis([0, 101, 0, 101])
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about `filter = (xgrid-50)**2 + (ygrid-50)**2 <= 25**2` followed by `ax.scatter(xgrid[filter], ygrid[filter])`?

Comment: Suspiciously similar question..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801021/draw-a-circle-using-matplotlib

Comment: JohanC 
Thank you! Your advice was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is collect the points that are in the circle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xgrid = []
ygrid = []

for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        if (x-50)*(x-50)+(y-50)*(y-50) < 25*25:
            xgrid.append(x)
            ygrid.append(y)


plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(xgrid, ygrid, s=5, color='green')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
ax.axis([0, 101, 0, 101])
plt.show()
```